# Fffected of cpu cache when use pipe(int pipefd[2])

Tags: c, linux, caching, pipe, cpu

I have wrpte a program to demonstrate of affected of CPU cache when using a pipe (int pipefd[2]) here: [linux-api/src/35-4](https://github.com/kevin-leptons/linux-api/blob/39fa798cba2293c82e164d2b5a6771ffb346a830/src/35-4.c). This is exercise 35-4 of Linux programming interface by Michael Kerrisk.

I compile and run that program on Intel i7-4770 and result is not expected. Time used in both cases is ~16 seconds.

-Two process transfer data though pipe. Two process run on same physical processor.
 - Two process transfer data though pipe. Two process run on different physical processor

Can anybody review my code and let me know the reasons?

Comment: What output does the program produce? How many CPUs does it report?

Comment: this is sample ouput

parent: pid=6235, cpuid=7, sending data
child: pid=6237, cpuid=7, receiving data
pipe on diff process: 16777216 times on 14 secs, -153171 usec

parent: pid=6235, cpuid=7, sending data
child: pid=6238, cpuid=6, receiving data
pipe on diff process: 16777216 times on 15 secs, 340745 usec